# Quiz interativo com usuários em LiveStream Youtube

Tags: php, api, youtube

Tenho algumas ideias sobre criar um aplicativo em php ou até mesmo em uma outra linguagem, onde o aplicativo responda interações do chat de uma livestream no youtube, por exemplo.

Uma pergunta exibe na live, se a pessoa que estiver assistindo acertar a pergunta com uma palavra já pré programada, esse nome da pessoa é exibido na live, junto da resposta, isso acontecendo simultaneamente em tempo real.

Andei vasculhando as api do youtube, mas não consegui clarear a mente, alguém tem uma sugestão?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, vendo um pouco da API que o youtube disponibiliza para ser utilizada, não existe uma forma de "socket". Portanto, você terá que ficar dando GET de tempos em tempos em um sala de chat específica para retornar uma lista das mensagens enviadas. Depois disso, coloque cada mensagem em uma pilha (para manter a integridade do momento em que a mensagem foi enviada), ou alguma estrutura do gênero e comece a varrer essa pilha procurando pelo o que você está interessado. Essa seria a forma que eu construiria uma aplicação deste tipo. Se existe alguma outra solução melhor, por favor me deixam saber! :D

Para que a mensagem correta seja exibida na tela, você precisará conectar essa aplicação com algum software de livestreaming (tipo: xplit, obs) por meio de algum plugin que você terá que implementar para eles. Para isso você terá que estudar um pouco mais sobre a API desses softwares também! Não entendo muito como que eles funcionam, mas sei que é por ai. Se eu não me engano, já deve existir algum plugin que realize as operações que você está querendo implementar. Tente estudá-los! :)

Aqui está a documentação que peguei como base para esse tipo de implementação que você está querendo fazer: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs

Vá até a sessão de "LiveChatMessages" e ali ele te dará as operações disponíveis para manipulação do chat.

Caso tenha falado algo errado, por favor me corrijam. Abraços!

Comment: Muito bem, ajudou muito, quando a mente trava, fica difícil de pensar em soluções, mas me ajudou cara, obrigado!